# SELECT a data using a keyword that exists in all columns (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Im working on a search panel and I want to SELECT all the data in all columns that has this certain keyword.

usually, if you want to select something, it goes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE columnName = "%as%";
```

but this only displays data that has "as" somewhere in that column I specified, I want to select all the data from all the columns that has that keyword.

here's what I want to happen:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE <any column> = "%as%";
```

please enlighten me if something like that exists. Thankyou.

Comment: It sounds like you're treating SQL tables in a similar way to a spreadsheet where all columns are "equal". Despite some superficial resemblances between them, you shouldn't be doing this. Generally, if two (or more) columns contain data that is the "same" (such that querying them both for the same thing, or performing calculations between them, etc), it's usually an indication that your data model is broken and that these ought to be a *single* column (and then, possibly, an additional column that should contain the *data* that has probably ended up in the column *names*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this trick

```
   select 
    mytable.* , FROM mytable
JOIN
( 
    select 
      id, 
      IFNULL(col1,'')+IFNULL(col2,'')+...+IFNULL(colN,'') concatenated
      FROM mytable
) T ON T.Id = mytable.Id
where   t.concatenated like '%x%'
```

this will concat all your column in one column and you can select over  this result

Comment: I think you mean `IFNULL`, not `ISNULL`.

Comment: @Raging Bull's answer works. This, I don't know, it's too complicated, and it displays "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'IsNULL'" error. thanks though

Comment: @user3663049 it looks complicated but  you can use other  "where" conditions with it easily , and for IFNULL just check parameter once, i dont have your schema so cant check it for error

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%as%'
   OR Col2 LIKE '%as%'
   OR Col3 LIKE '%as%'
   OR Col4 LIKE '%as%'
   OR Col5 LIKE '%as%'
```